# sbt-release plugin logs git push as error, despite it succeeding

Tags: sbt, sbt-release

I am using the sbt-release plugin.

The process seems to work, however, sbt logs the final release step, `pushChanges` as error.  Ideally, only actual errors are logged to error output as it can confuse the automation.

Sample output here:

```
Push changes to the remote repository (y/n)? [y] y
[error] To git@git.mycompany.com:gsilin/s3-client.git
[error]    67277ef..a1b959f  my_branch -> my_branch
[error] To git@git.mycompany.com:gsilin/s3-client.git
[error]  * [new tag]         v0.1.8 -> v0.1.8
```

my_branch in this case is not the master branch (as I'm testing this process on my own branch before it goes to master), could that be the issue?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if something's changed in the latest version, but before sbt-release was warning you before this push step, that git sends it's info on stderr and so it will be shown with error messages in sbt although the process goes perfectly fine. So it's ok, don't worry.